# Django, I want to save extra/custom field in built in django registration form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

i am using UserCreationForm to register user but i need an extra field to add and save. i did it but it does not save in auth_user model. The extra field i named is accntype and i dont even see the field accntype created in auth_model, rest is being saved. My code is a whole mess sorry for that.

my form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class signup(UserCreationForm):
    choice = (('visitor', 'Visitor'),('guest', 'Guest'),('contractor', 'Contractor'))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField( required=True)
    accntype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice ,required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('accntype', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.accntype = self.cleaned_data["accntype"]
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

here is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .form import signup
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.

def signupview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.type = form.cleaned_data['accntype']
            user.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = signup()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

signup.html

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css' href="{%static 'css/signup.css'%}">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Sign-up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class='header'>
                <img src="{%static 'img/healthlogo.png'%}" height="80" weidth="80">
                <h1  align='center'>AGED CARE PORTAL
                </h1>
            </div>
        <form method="POST" class="form">
             {%csrf_token%}
             {%for error in form.errors%}
                {{error}}
             {%endfor%}
             <div align='center'>
                <select class='selector' {{form.accntype}}
                <br>
                <input class='credentials' placeholder='username' {{form.username}}
                <br>
                <input class='credentials' placeholder='First Name' {{form.first_name}}
                <br>
                <input class='credentials' placeholder='Last Name' {{form.last_name}}
                <br>
                <input class='credentials' placeholder='Email' {{form.email}}
                <br>
                <input class='credentials' placeholder='Password' {{form.password1}}
                <br>
                <input class='credentials' placeholder='Confirm Password' {{form.password2}}
                <p align='center'><input  class='logtton' type='submit' value='Register'></p> 
              </div>           
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i am a beginner sorry for the dumb mistakes i make. Please help me, i did a lot of searching

Comment: When you say "auth_user model" and "auth_model", do you mean the database table `auth_user`? To write the new form field to the database table, you would need to add it to the `User` model first, so that a new database column is created when you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Currently, you only added it to the form that is displayed in the browser.

Comment: @C14L i mean auth_user model. i am lost how do i add field to User? Thanks a lot for help